# Show initial form in Ant Design sample form

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm recreating this sample code in my app from Ant Design
[Dynamic Form Item](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-curran-1hezi). But I want the fields show when initalized.
Right now I need to click add item button first before showing it up.

Comment: You just have to find this line and populate the empty array with the name of the fields;getFieldDecorator("keys", { initialValue: [] }); Eg. getFieldDecorator("keys", { initialValue: ["name", "age"  ] });

Comment: Thank you! Got it by adding ```{ initialValue: ['names'] }```  in the example. In my case, I started it by ```data```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `options.initialValue` of [`getFieldDecorator`](https://ant.design/components/form/#getFieldDecorator(id,-options)-parameters), or you can use `mapPropsToFields` of [`Form.create`](https://ant.design/components/form/#Formcreate(options)), depending on your use case - they both populate form values on initialization..

You can find official examples within the docs: [`mapPropsToState`](https://codesandbox.io/s/kqwx7), [`initialState`](https://codesandbox.io/s/ywckq).

```
// Initial input form item with 'Passenger-X' value.

getFieldDecorator(`names[${k}]`, {
  initialValue: `Passenger - ${k}`,
  validateTrigger: ['onChange', 'onBlur'],
  rules: [
    {
      required: true,
      whitespace: true,
      message: "Please input passenger's name or delete this field."
    }
  ]
});
```

[image: Edit Q-58632222-InitialValue]

Comment: I already got the answer from MiDas. But your answer is very useful in the future!